# How to find rows that match all these conditions

Tags: mysql, select, join, rows, multiple-columns

I've two tables:

first: table_a

```
id | orderid
1    123
2    456
...
```

second: table_b

```
orderid | status | date
123       2        1380566559
123       4        1380566561
123       6        1380566563
```

I want to return the orderid rows from table_a only when an orderid has the status 2 and dont has status 4 and 6 in my tables ...

I tried without success :(

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a.orderid) 
FROM table_a AS a 
INNER JOIN table_b AS b 
INNER JOIN table_b AS c 
INNER JOIN table_b AS d 
ON a.orderid = b.orderid 
WHERE b.status = 2 AND
c.status != 4 AND
d.status != 6;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.orderid
FROM table_a AS a 
INNER JOIN table_b AS b on a.orderid = b.orderid
group by a.orderid
having sum(b.status = 2) >= 1
and sum(b.status in (4,6)) = 0
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fc7f/4)

Comment: Hi, mysql returns an empty reuslt. that query runs but doenst gives me the row

Comment: @JuCh: I changed it so records will not be returned if they have **both** status 4 and 6.

Comment: Hi juergen, i tried but now i got an empty reuslt. the databse must deliver the orderid 456 because this orderid has no entrys with 4 and 6

Comment: @JuCh: Of course. The join condition was missing. Did not notice it.

Comment: Great :) I Think that works fine. Thanks a lot all for bringing the solution :) You made my day!

Answer (score -1):

Can you run below query to get the oupput.

```
select 
    order_id 
from table_a a 
    inner join table_b b 
        on a.order_id = b.order_id 
where b.status=2;
```

Comment: Hi, this also dont works, gives me also rows that dont match. i tried: select a.orderid from table_a a inner join table_b b on a.orderid = b.orderid where b.status=2 AND b.status != 4 AND b.status != 6;

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a.orderid)
FROM table_a a, table_b b
WHERE a.orderid = b.orderid
      AND b.status = 2
      AND b.status != 4
      AND b.status !=6
```

and you can verify by using the below link
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9b89/5/0

Comment: hi hari. thanks for your help, but this also returns me two orderid-rows. orderid 123 has all 3 status inserts but the id 456 has only one insert with status 2.

Comment: I tried with the data as you mentioned but I'm getting only one row.. refer the link [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ded9/1). let me know if I didn't understand correctly..

Comment: hi hari, look here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3fa2/1
orderid 123 is also found, but thats not correct because it has status 2 and 4,6